# ¿Por qué al emplear printf("%s", char *[]) se imprime (null)?

Tags: c, string

Buenas tardes.

Necesito ayuda porque no logro encontrar explicación a la pregunta.

En concreto trato de probar `mi_strcpy` y `mi_strcat` y al emplear `printf` sale (null)

¿Por qué?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CERO 1
#define UNO 2
#define DOS 3

int mi_strlen(char *str){
    int num_char;
    while(*str!='\0'){
        num_char++;
        str++;
    }
    return num_char;
}

char* mi_strcpy(char *s1, char *s2){
    while(*s2!='\0'){
        *s1 = *s2;
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    *s1 = '\0';
    return s1;
}

char* mi_strcat(char* s1, char* s2){
    char concatena[mi_strlen(s1)+mi_strlen(s2)+1];
    char *con_ptr;
    con_ptr = concatena;
    while(*s1!='\0'){
        *con_ptr=*s1;
        con_ptr++;
        s1++;
    }
    while(*s2!='\0'){
        *con_ptr=*s2;
        con_ptr++;
        s2++;
    }
    con_ptr++;
    *con_ptr='\0';
    s1=concatena;
    return s1;
}

int main(void) {
    char *str;
    char str_uno[UNO] = "A";
    char str_cero[CERO] = "";
    char str_espacios[DOS] = "  ";
    char str_copiada[11];

    str = str_uno;
    int cuenta = mi_strlen(str);

    printf("Cuenta %d y debería ser %d\n", cuenta, UNO-1);

    str = str_cero;
    cuenta = mi_strlen(str);

    printf("Cuenta %d y debería ser %d\n", cuenta, CERO-1);

    str = str_espacios;
    cuenta = mi_strlen(str);

    printf("Cuenta %d y debería ser %d\n", cuenta, DOS-1);

    char *s1;
    char *s2;
    s1 = str_copiada;
    s2 = str_uno;
    printf("s1 es: \"%s\" y debería ser s2: %s\n",*mi_strcpy(s1,s2),s2);

    char str_copiada2[11];
    s1 = str_copiada2;
    s2 = str_cero;
    printf("s1 es: \"%s\" y debería ser s2: \"%s\"\n",*mi_strcpy(s1,s2),s2);

    char str_copiada3[11];
    s1 = str_copiada3;
    s2 = str_espacios;
    printf("s1 es: \"%s\" y debería ser s2: \"%s\"\n",*mi_strcpy(s1,s2),s2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ups! falta inicializar  num_char; en el método: mi_strlen(char *str), como comenta rnd en su respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

sobre `mi_strcpy` podria cambiar `*mi_strcpy(s1,s2),s2);`

```
printf("s1 es: \"%s\" y debería ser s2: %s\n",*mi_strcpy(s1,s2),s2);
```

por

```
printf("s1 es: \"%s\" y debería ser s2: %s\n",mi_strcpy(s1,s2),s2);
```

Basandose en su codigo usted tendria que almacenar la direccion inicial en `s1` pues usted la cambia, al hacer `s1++` y en el return la direccion no es la inical a cambiado.

ejemplo sencillo:

```
int a = 0;
a++;
a++;
a++;
```

¿cuanto vale a? pues si la pasara valdria lo que se le incremento no el valor inicial pues es mas o menos lo mismo espero entienda.

---

Sin tener que lidiar con eso usted puede manejarlo por ejemplo asi, echandole un poco de azucar:

```
char* mi_strcpy(char* d, char* s) {
   int c = 0;

   while (s[c] != '\0') {
      d[c] = s[c];
      c++;
   }
   d[c] = '\0';

   return d;
}
```

https://ideone.com/02YmKw

Comment: tienes razón angel, cuando lo compile quite esos * que no van alli. luego lo olvide cuando postie :)

Answer (score 0):

Primero a `mi_strlen` le falta inicializar `num_char`, por eso da cualquier valor y causa fallos en `mi_strcat`...

```
int mi_strlen(char *str){
        int num_char = 0; /* falta =0 */
        while(*str!='\0'){
                num_char++;
                str++;
        }
        return num_char;
}
```

Luego a `mi_strcopy`, estas retornado `s1` con todos los `++` acumulados, osea que apunta a la ultima posicion del string. Lo que puedes hacer es guardar en una variable intermedia el valor original y retornarlo al final... algo asi:

```
char* mi_strcpy(char *s1, char *s2){
        char *origAddr = s1; /* almacenas donde empieza la cadena */
        while(*s2!='\0'){
                *s1 = *s2;
                s1++; /* se acumula el ++ y se pierde el inicio */
                s2++;
        }
        *s1 = '\0'; 
        return origAddr; /* retornas donde empieza la cadena, s1 apunta al \0 */
}
```

Lo mismo pasa en `mi_strcat`.. pero, te dejo esa modificación a ti, puesto que ya sabes cual es el problema con la forma en que incrementas los punteros.

Por ultimo, cuando haces:

```
printf("s1 es: \"%s\" y debería ser s2: %s\n",*mi_strcpy(s1,s2),s2);
```

El `*` delante de `mi_strcpy` esta demás, pues `mi_strcpy` retorna `char*`.